# How can I uninstall a package using Monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, android-emulator, monkeyrunner

What is wrong with this script?

```
 # Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
```

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
```

```
# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
```

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
```

```
 #Uninstall package
```

```
 device.removePackage ('MyApp.apk')
```

I also tried using the path of the application and didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
device.removePackage 'com.mypackage.myapp'
```